# Random Segmentation Fault C++

Tags: c++, hash, segmentation-fault

I compile the file once, and run it with the same output, and I get a segmentation fault only about 20-30% of the time. I just emailed my professor, but she is taking forever. I really have no idea why, especially because the error does not occur all the time, but only sometimes with the exact same a.out file. I know exactly where the error occurs, which is from if( sDB[index] == 0 ).

Thanks for the help,

Please let me know if more code is needed to solve the issue.

*sDB is and array of pointers initialized in my constructor:

```
*sDB = new HashElem[MAX];
```

structs:

```
struct Elem { 
    student *info;
    Elem *next;
};

struct HashElem {
    student *info;
    HashElem *next; 
};
```

snippets of my code:

```
void studentsDB::push( student *std ) {

Elem *e = new Elem;
e->info = std;

Elem *cur = head;
while( cur->next != 0 ) 
    cur = cur->next;

cur->next = e;
e->next = 0;

int index = std->hash( );

HashElem *h = new HashElem;
h->info = std;;
if( sDB[index] == 0 ) { //<<< THIS LINE CAUSES THE ERROR
    sDB[index] = h; 
    h->next = 0;
}
else {
    HashElem *ha = sDB[index];
    while( ha->next != 0 ) {
        ha = ha->next;
    }
    ha->next = h;
}

size++;
}
```

hash():

```
int student::hash( ) {
int ret = 0;
string s = id;

for( int i = 0; i < s.length( ); i++ )
    ret = 33 * ret + s[i];

return ret % MAX;
}
```

output:

```
bash-4.2$ g++ *.cpp
bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
Segmentation fault

bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
Segmentation fault

bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 626 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 605 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 915 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 915 +++
printList
Flintstone, Fred 000-12SA 3 121314 12333 12116 
Flintstone, Wilma 000-45SA 2 12332 12111 
Glotz, Joe Q 901-9984 3 12332 12116 12111 
Rubble, Barney 001-01SA 3 121314 12111 12116 
CS001 1 12111 1 10 3 000-45SA 901-9984 001-01SA 
CS515 2 121314 4 45 2 000-12SA 001-01SA 
CH302 1 12116 5 15 3 000-12SA 901-9984 001-01SA 
MA111 1 12333 4 15 1 000-12SA 
PH999 1 12999 2 10 0000-12SA901-9984 
PY000 3 12332 6 5 2 000-45SA 901-9984 

bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
Segmentation fault

bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
Segmentation fault

bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 626 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 605 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 915 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 915 +++
printList
Flintstone, Fred 000-12SA 3 121314 12333 12116 
Flintstone, Wilma 000-45SA 2 12332 12111 
Glotz, Joe Q 901-9984 3 12332 12116 12111 
Rubble, Barney 001-01SA 3 121314 12111 12116 
CS001 1 12111 1 10 3 000-45SA 901-9984 001-01SA 
CS515 2 121314 4 45 2 000-12SA 001-01SA 
CH302 1 12116 5 15 3 000-12SA 901-9984 001-01SA 
MA111 1 12333 4 15 1 000-12SA 
PH999 1 12999 2 10 0000-12SA901-9984 
PY000 3 12332 6 5 2 000-45SA 901-9984 

bash-4.2$ ./a.out students.dat courses.dat 
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 626 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 605 +++
+++ After +++
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 915 +++
Segmentation fault
```

gdb output:

```
Starting program: /home/csu/dtk24/cs515/prog11/a.out students.dat courses.dat
begin
objects created
+++ Before the if statement +++
+++ 548 +++

Program received signal SIGSEGV, Segmentation fault.
0x0804b2a0 in studentsDB::push (this=0xbffff78c, std=0x8054120)
    at studentsDB.cpp:130
130     if( sDB[index] == 0 ) {
```

Comment: How do you know that the hash value returned by `std->hash()` is valid for the range of `sDB` (which is `MAX`)?

Comment: What are the possible outputs of the hash function? Did you check if sDB was allocated every single time? Can you post the code for std->hahs()?

Comment: earlier, I outputted the hash value before the if statment, and they were the same and valid every time. MAX is 1000.

Comment: Well, if `index` isn't the problem, what about `sDB`? Has that been properly allocated every time?

Comment: I'm pretty sure, I initialized it in the constructor. I will shortly post the sample output, but it doesn't have to be re-compiled to cause/fix the error.

Comment: What Greg Hewgill was basically asking you to do is if (sDB == NULL) // call exit with error message.

Comment: I see, and yes I've tried that, but causes the same problem. I've also posted a sample output, and notice how I compile only once, but get an error sometimes. The number is the output from the hash() function.

Comment: Can you do the following? g++ -g your program then run gdb ./a.out then keep typing run until segmentation fault. Once you get segmentation fault type bt. Post that output please.

Comment: include the -g flag for debugging. 
run gdb yourProgram.  
type run.  
when it segfaults, type bt.  
see what function your program crashed in.

Comment: `*sDB = new HashElem[MAX];` doesn't seem like an array of pointers could you show us the whole code of how you have declared `sDB`

Comment: Wait a minute, if I am guessing that sDB is of type HashElem then why are you comparing HashElem to 0? HashElem is a struct. Can you even do that? When I tried doing that I got HashElem doesn't have a == operator.

Comment: keety, thanks. that was the issue.

Answer (score 0):

There is not sufficient code included in your question to be able to say for sure what the problem is.

However if I should venture a guess, then problem is likely to be in hash() -- which depending on how you do the calculation ends up with a negative number, or a number larger than the max of the hash table

Answer (score 0):

You wrote a double ";" character.
The error is caused at the line before the if.

Comment: Looking at the comments above, The issue was already found (in April, 2012). The issue was never an empty statement (ie. `something; ;`).